# how to remain the form open when x button(in the upper right most) is clicked?

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem with my form in VB.net. I want to remain my form open when I clicked no in the decision box.

this is my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
        If (MsgBox("Do you want to quit now?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo).ToString = "Yes") Then
            Dim login As New login
            login.Show()
        Else
            'remain my form
        End If
    End Sub
```

Please help me. thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the **Cancel** property of the **e** parameter to **True**.

```
e.Cancel = True
```

For more info, check the [Form.FormClosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [Form.Closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx)) event.